# A foreign key constraint fails (I have an emp with the primary key that I want to connect it with emp_phones)

Tags: java, mysql

Constraint failed between `EMPNO` from `Employee_phone` and `EMPNO` from 
`Employee`. I am trying to add a new phone in `employee_phone` table with the 
number of the employee `EMPNO`

**/file.java**

```
public class Employee_Phones implements MainData{ 

private int EmpNO;
private String phones;

public int getEmpNO() {
    return EmpNO;
}

public void setEmpNO(int empno) {
    this.EmpNO = empno;
}

public String getEmp_phones() {
    return phones;
}

public void setEmp_phones(String emp_phones) {
    this.phones = emp_phones;
}

@Override
public void add() {
     String stradd = "Insert into Employee_Phones values("
             + "EMPNO=" + EmpNO + ","
             + "phone='" + phones + "')" ;
     boolean isadd = db.go.runNonQuery(stradd);
     if(isadd){
         //Tools.msgBox("Phone Is Added");
     }
}
```

Code from **button's click listener** to test:

```
Employee_Phones e = new Employee_Phones();
e.setEmpNO(1);
e.setEmp_phones("011");
e.add();
```

**/file.mysql**

```sql
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT(
  DEPTNO INT PRIMARY KEY,
  DEPTNAME VARCHAR(120) UNIQUE,
  LOCATION VARCHAR(200)
);

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(
  EMPNO INT PRIMARY KEY,
  EMPNAME VARCHAR (120) UNIQUE,
  ADDRESS VARCHAR (200),
  SALARY DOUBLE ,
  HIRINGDATE DATE ,
  BIRTHDATE DATE ,
  DEPTNO INT ,
  FOREIGN KEY (DEPTNO) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT (DEPTNO)
);

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_PHONES(
  EMPNO INT ,
  PHONE VARCHAR(55) ,
  PRIMARY KEY(EMPNO,PHONE) ,
  FOREIGN KEY (EMPNO) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (EMPNO)
);

SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Id = 1;
```

Comment: Could you add the exact error message you receive? Then we can tell you precicely what do check for (as MySQL usually is correct when it tells you that the referenced key does not exist, but you might do something different than you think you do).

Comment: Cannot add or update a child row: A foreign key constraint fails ('company'.'employee_phones',CONSTRAINT fails 'employee_phones_ibfk_1'FOREIGN KEY('EMPNO) REFRENCES 'employee' ('EMPNO') )

Comment: This tells you that you do not have an employee with `EMPNO` `1` in your table `EMPLOYEE`. So check this first: `select * from EMPLOYEE where EMPNO = 1`.

Comment: it shows me the employee with empno = 1 normally thats why iam sharing the problem....

Comment: its so weird and i dont know what to do

Comment: Could you try to manually add that entry, e.g. directly executing the query `insert into EMPLOYEE_PHONES (EMPNO, PHONE) values (1, '011')` (with a mysql client, not your framework). If it fails, run the `select` from above in the same session/client. If it does not fail, we have the next piece of the puzzle.